# Need to update the input value on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried with this

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" class="change-txt">
<div class="dtmp">
    <input type="text" value="Rachael Senders">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
   var $input =  $('.dtmp input');
   $input.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.change-txt').val($input.val());
    });
   $input.on('keyup', function(){
        $('.change-txt').val($input.val());
        //need to update the input value here
   });
});
```

I need to update the input value according to the value of hidden input.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why on click instead of keyup? You need to update the hidden inputs value to reflect the non-hidden one you mean? Confusing wording

Comment: Don't bind events handlers in the context of other event handlers.

Comment: @dsg I need to save the same value as the hidden field when changing the input text. Actually the value is not updated when changing the input text.. I don't understand .. why?

Comment: You should not bind the event "keyup" inside the "click" event because that way the event handler will be binded as many times the "click" event get's fired.

Comment: @ Vohuman plz write a solution here

Comment: I don't understand who are this person making (-1). What is wrong with this question?

Comment: The dev who gave me (-) I don't know if s/he even write a single line of code in his life or not. If you have skill plz solve this question and prove yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try only this code:

```
$(function(){  
  var $input = $('.dtmp input');
  $input.on('keyup', function(){
     $('.change-txt').val($input.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: this is not the solution what I mean. It will update the hidden field value not the input value itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dtmp input').on('keyup', function(e){
                $('.change-txt').val($(this).val());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you change the value of your hidden input element you need to trigger the "change" event like this:

```
$('.change-txt').val('...').trigger('change');
```

And then use:

```
$('.change-txt').change(function(e) {
  $('.dtmp input').val($(this).val());
  // do other stuff if necessary ... 
});
```

OTHERWISE

You can set an interval for checking the value of the hidden input and updating the other.

```
setInterval(function(){
   if ($('.change-txt').val()!=$('.dtmp input').val()){
       $('.dtmp input').val($('.change-txt').val());
   }
}, 100);
```